# Reading JSONs in Azure Synapse Notebooks with Multiple Lines

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Good afternoon,

I'm attempting to read log data into an Azure Synapse notebook using a Pyspark dataframe. Currently the data lives in a container, and I'm attempting to access it via it's link:

```
abfss://insights-logs-integrationpipelineruns@{x}.dfs.core.windows.net/resourceId=....
```

but I'm running into an issue in that the JSON file includes multiple lines

`{ "Level": 4, "correlationId": "x", "time": "y", "runId": "z", "resourceId":...}`

`{ "Level": 4, "correlationId": "a", "time": "b", "runId": "c", "resourceId":...}`

`{ "Level": 4, "correlationId": "d", "time": "e", "runId": "f", "resourceId":...}`

I tried using the native spark.read.json method, and also by setting the multiline option to true as follows:

```
df = spark.read.option("multiLine","true").json(uri)
```

But I get the following error:

**AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema: `level`**

The thing is, the data I need is nested inside each line. If there's a way to just load the JSON file as a dictionary, I'd know how to parse it so that I could get the data I need.

Otherwise, if there's no way to do that, is there a way for me to specify pyspark to only read portions of a file?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my notebook fixed my issue:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "true")
```